# Shutting down applications using our files

Tags: installation, inno-setup, silent

I had an installer that was built using Inno Setup 5.0.8, and i just rebuilt this installer using Inno Setup 5.5.3 (Latest version by now).

In the version built with the older IS version, when a file was being used by another application, it was automatically ignoring it, without any prompt to the user.

However, the version built with new Inno Setup prompts the user when it can't close automatically (it's a feature added on v5.5.3), but i'm caling the installer in silent mode, which second to the version's revision history, shouldn't, as said here:

```
"Restart Manager: If Setup is not running silently and is unable to close all      applications using files that need to be updated, it will now ask the user to abort, retry, or ignore. Previously it always ignored."
```

And as i said, i'm calling the installer in silent mode through /verysilent command line parameter, and still it says it couldn't close the applications, and prompts the user, instead ignoring it (like Inno setup's older version did).

By what i've readed in Inno's setup documentation, there are no options in the  /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES to ignore it.

So, finally, the question is, is there a way i can make my installer to act as the older version, by ignoring it automatically, without having to prompt the user(which already shouldn't happen since it is running silently)?

Comment: This seems to be [`intended behavior`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Wizard.pas#L2716), which you might try to workaround by running the setup with `/NoRestart` parameter. But it's just taken from a quick view in the source. Cannot verify this at this time...

Comment: Yes but i'm already using /NoRestart as well..
The parameters im using are pretty simple its just calling like that      "install.exe /verysilent /norestart"

Comment: @TLama, The link you posted was for when the PrepareToInstall code function returns an error message.  There's a comment there that specifically says that the code path isn't triggered when application closing fails.

Comment: Typically the [`/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm#SUPPRESSMSGBOXES) parameter is intended for this, but this will make that particular box default to 'Abort'.  You should probably [file an issue](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues?state=open) for this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As i don't see any solution for this, i had to tell my installer that it mustn't try to close any application, and so it will warn the user when the file is being used (which sounds better than warning it couldn't close the apps), and so the user can decide if he will close or not the application. 

It was not the intended behavior, but this was the best way i found for now.
But anyway  /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES should have the option to 'IGNORE' it, as you said.

Thank you all, again.